# Bootstrap 3 - multiple active buttons with minimum one selected

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have these multiple selection buttons. What should I do so that the user cannot uncheck them all. There has to be at least one button selected, if not more:

```
<div class="container">
    <br><p>Click all the fruits that you like</p>
    <div class="btn-group col-xs-12" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" id="apple" value="apple">apple
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" id="pear" value="pear">pear
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" id="orange" value="orange">orange
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/o1jwc7h7/

Add this jquery:

```
$('.btn-group input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    if ($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length == 0) {
       $(this).prop("checked",true).parent().addClass('active');
       alert("at least one of them should be checked");
    }
});
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly well in jsfiddle, but for an unknown reason it does not in my code. I tried moving the scripts to the top of the page to make sure they are all loaded, but sitll nothing...

Comment: @Tuntex Use ready() to make a function available after the document is loaded Like this : **$(document).ready(function(){ /* Code behind */ });**